# Inflection point of Black & Scholes formula for implied volatility using Newton - Raphson Algorithm

Tags: partial-derivative, maxima-minima, finance, newton-raphson

We have the formula for pricing the call type of an option under the Black Scholes formula (European type) :

$$C(S_t,t;K,T)= S_t \cdot e^{-D(T-t)} \cdot\Phi(d_+) - K\cdot e^{-r(T-t)} \cdot\Phi(d_-)$$
where $d_{\pm}$ is given by :

$$d_{\pm} = \frac{\log(S_t/K)+(r-D\pm\frac{1}{2}\cdot \sigma^2) \cdot (T-t)}{\sigma \cdot \sqrt(T-t)} $$

The Vega measure of sensitivity is the first partial derivative of $C(S_t,t;K,T)$ with respect to $\sigma$ and is defined as : $$\mathcal{V}_{ega}= \sqrt{\frac{T-t}{2\pi}} S_t \cdot e^{-D \cdot (T-t)} \cdot e^{-\frac{1}{2} \cdot d_{+}^2}$$

I am trying to implement the Newton-Raphson method for the calculation of the implied (forward looking) volatility of an option. In order for the algorithm to ensure convergence we must find the inflation point, i.e the point that the function changes convexity or the interval that the function is convex and beyond that it becomes concave. For the Black Scholes formula this interval is (Manaster & Koehler Seed Value) : $$\left(0, \sqrt{ \frac{2 \cdot \log(\frac{S_t \cdot e^{r(T-t)}}{K} )}{T} } \right] $$.
In order to find this interval one must implement the second derivative test to check in which point the $f''(x)=0$ (in general).For the Black Scholes this is the Vomma sensitivity measure which is the second derivative with respect to volatility $\sigma$ and is given by :
$$\mathcal{V}_{omma}= \sqrt{\frac{T-t}{2\pi}} K \cdot e^{-r \cdot (T-t)} \cdot e^{-\frac{1}{2} \cdot d_{-}^2} \cdot \left(\frac{d_+ \cdot d_- }{2}\right)$$

My question is this interval was a result of such a calculation ? And if I am not correct how this interval is calculated ?

Comment: First time that I hear what we have to do to implement Newton-Raphson for implied vol. The option price is a strictly increasing function of the vol (see the vega). Therefore the implied vol is unique. For Newton-Raphson all you need is a starting value and the first derivative (vega). NR is one of the simplest algorithms to implement. It works well when the option is not too far ITM or OTM.

Comment: @KurtG. the starting value of the NR must be $$\sigma_{0} = \sqrt{ \frac{2 \frac{\log{S_t e^{-r(t-t)}}}{K} }{T}}$$.And my question is how is this must occurred ?See also [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/58634/newtons-algorithm-for-implied-volatility)

Comment: The [answer](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/58636/58786) to this QSE question shows that that "must" is not a must at all. Try the simplest NR implementation you can think of. When it does not converge quickly for a starting value it will typically not converge for any starting value because it is far ITM/OTM.

Comment: Must was an autocorrect option I meant “number” instead of “must”.I get it.If I peak any number as a starting point it will converge if it is near in the money or out of the money.But why and how they peak this starting value.

Comment: Why don't you take the $\sigma_0$ there ? Numerical maths is an art not just a science.